# PrintDocument PrintPageEventArgs c# wpf PageSize WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, impressão

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(arquivoImpressao);
  pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("teste", 300, 600);
  PrintPreviewDialog printPrvDlg2 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
  ((Form)printPrvDlg2).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  printPrvDlg2.Document = pd;
  printPrvDlg2.ShowDialog();
  printDocument.DocumentName = descricao;
  pd.Print();
```

Quando ele abre o `PrintPreviewDialog`, ele mostra corretamente na imagem, porém quando ele imprime na impressora PDF ("Microsoft Print to PDF"), ela gera no tamanho da A4. Onde estou errando?

Fiz um teste no Word e fiz uma modificação no tamanho no papel, quando foi gerado, o papel ficou conforme o tamanho estipulado no Word, no caso, acredito que o problema esteja mesmo no C#.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você mudou o tamanho da folha mas não informou ao sistema de impressão que deseja usar um tamanho de folha personalizada através do valor [`PaperKind.Custom`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.paperkind?view=netframework-4.7.2). O que faz que o sistema escolha o tamanho na falta(A4 no Brasil ou Letter no USA) e faça a escalonamento da imagem para a página.

Para corrigir esse problema você precisa modificar a propriedade [RawKind](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.papersize.rawkind?view=netframework-4.7.2) do objeto PaperSize para 119 que indica ao sistema de impressão sua intenção em usar um tamanho de folha personalizado.

Seu código vai ficar aproximadamente assim:

```
  PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
  pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(arquivoImpressao);
  pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("teste", 300, 600);
  //******************modificação***************************//

  pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = 119;

  //*******************************************************//
  PrintPreviewDialog printPrvDlg2 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
  ((Form)printPrvDlg2).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
  printPrvDlg2.Document = pd;
  printPrvDlg2.ShowDialog();
  printDocument.DocumentName = descricao;
  pd.Print();
```

Comment: adicionei esse elemento, mas está dando erro, o RawKind não aceita esse valor, por serem valores diferente

Comment: A documentação do [RawKind](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.papersize.rawkind?view=netframework-4.7.2) diz que para folha personalizada deve ser usado um inteiro maior que 118. Vou fazer a alteração.

Answer (score -1):

já que você fez a alteração no tamanho do papel, você poderia mudar nesta linha

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("teste", 300, 600);
```

colocar no tamanho do papel na qual você conseguiu imprimir

> Fiz um teste no word e fiz uma modificação no tamanho no papel...

Faça a mesma alteração no C#

Comment: eu to fazendo a alteração... essa é a linha que estou colocando, mas quando imprime ele imprime no A4

Comment: mas eu falo alterar essa linha, ao invés de 300,600 , colocar outro valor que fique correspondente ao que você usou no word

Comment: fiz esse teste e não funciona, só funciona no visualizar, porem quando "imprimo" no pdf ele gera no A4

Comment: configure uma impressora qualquer para imprimir em determinado tamanho pelo tipo de papel no gerenciador de dispositivos do seu computador, entao use printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "nomeImpressora"; as vezes se fizer isso vc consegue